# Make list of dictionary from 3 lists where each list data is key in dictionary

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

..better solutions.

I have got following 3 list

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c']
c = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']
```

I need to a create a list of dictionaries out of these list in as follows:

```
[{'address': 'aa', 'id': 1, 'name': 'a'}, {'address': 'bb', 'id': 2, 'name': 'b'
}, {'address': 'cc', 'id': 3, 'name': 'c'}]
```

I have done this with following code which works. I am interested in knowing is there any better way to do it.

```
>>> d = [dict(zip(['id', 'name', 'address'], i)) for i in zip(a, b, c)]
>>> d
[{'address': 'aa', 'id': 1, 'name': 'a'}, {'address': 'bb', 'id': 2, 'name': 'b'
}, {'address': 'cc', 'id': 3, 'name': 'c'}]
```

Comment: + for your own answer :)

Comment: Belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - You might get more feedback there :)

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
from itertools import izip, repeat

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c']
c = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']

addresses = repeat('address')
ids = repeat('id')
names = repeat('names')

d = [dict(((i, j), (k, l), (m, n))) for i, j, k, l, m, n in izip(addresses, a, ids, b, names, c)]
```

Re: slower - I tried to simply benchmark it:

```
from time import time
t = time()
for i in xrange(100000):
    d = [dict(((i, j), (k, l), (m, n))) for i, j, k, l, m, n in izip(addresses, a, ids, b, names, c)]
print time() - t
```

gives 0.68 seconds, the OP's way gives 0.81 seconds.

Re 2: and the fastest way (and IMHO also simplest) is:

```
d = [{'address': j, 'id': l, 'names': n} for j, l, n in izip(a, b, c)]
```

giving 0.23 seconds.

Comment: I don't know. This is more complicated, slower and harder to read than the original solution.

Comment: Just define a new tuple/list instead of using `repeat`: keys = ('id', 'name', 'address') and code reduces to: `[dict(izip(keys, x)) for x in izip(a,b,c)]`

Comment: You're right, it's not slower. I just timed it myself (the correct way, using `timeit.timeit()` with proper setup/statement separation), and your version is faster. Most of the speed improvement goes away when using `izip` instead of `zip` in the OP's version, although there still remains a speed advantage.